# How can I display the url of a page in concourse pipeline so that I can click the url in the pipeline to jump to the corresponding page

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-fly

I am trying to create a concourse pipeline where there should be a url link and that link should be clickable to jump to the corresponding page. Here is my code which is giving the static link.

```yaml
- task: url-link    
  config:
   platform: linux
   image_resource: 
    type: xyz resource
    source:
     repository: docker.xyz/my-repo
  run:
    path: echo
    args: [ "http://example.com/pipeline" ]
```

So, here `https://example.com/pipeline` is displayed in the pipeline. But this is a static link that I need to copy and paste to the browser and click to go to the page. I want this link be clickable so that once I click in this link, I can directly jump to the page.
Another thing I want is to put version at the end of the link like `https://example.com/pipeline/version`.
This version will be dynamic meaning that it will change every time i run the pipeline.

So, What should be my code to insert the url along with the changing version in the concourse yml file?

Comment: What should this `version` be?

Answer (score 1):

Any output from tasks and resources are treated as text, there is no highlighting in them.
Only in the resource metadata that links will be parsed as such.

[image: concourse-resource-link]